# Running code only for tests using Jasmine package

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-jasmine

I am using the `sanjo:jasmine` and `velocity:html-reporter` packages in my app to try and implement some unit and integration testing.  Using this tutorial as a guide, I have a few unit tests and a couple integration tests done.  What I am not able to figure out is how to get code to run in the "test" environment that is not part of a unit test or integration test, but needs to run prior to the tests and only for the tests.

What I am trying to solve is that I need some dummy users created for testing, but I do not want them in my production app.  Sort of like an "init" phase where you can build the mockups and insert any data you need.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using `mike:mocha` and as long as your specs are written inside a folder called tests (and then client / server, respectively) then Velocity puts data in velocity specific collections. I run the same Meteor method I use to insert a document in my main app, but velocity knows to put it in the mirrored version.

Comment: Perfect!  Works great.

Answer (score 2):

1. **I would recommend that you create some seed or fake data for your tests using factories**.

   I would recommend that you try the following packages:

   - [anti:fake](https://atmospherejs.com/anti/fake) - Fake text and data generator for Meteor.js
   - [dburles:factory](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/factory) - A package for creating test data or for generating fixtures.
2. **You can install these packages using this command:**

   `meteor add anti:fake dburles:factory`
3. **Create your factory data for the test environment only**.

I'd create a file called *`server/seeds.js`* with the following content:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  Factory.define('user', Users, {
      username: "test-user",
      name: "Test user",
      email: "test@example.com"
      // add any other fields you need
  });

  var numberOfUsers = 10;

  // Ensure this is the test environment
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {

    // Create the users from the factory definition
    _(numberOfUsers).times(function(n) {
      Factory.create('user');
    });
  }
});
```

You can follow this **Factory** approach for any data, not just Users.

**If your Users need to login**, such as when you're using `accounts:base`, then I would consider an alternative approach to using Factory data:

```
var email = "test@example.com";
var password = "secret";
var name = "Test user";

Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password, profile: {name: name}});
```

Please see [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) in the Meteor docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `sanjo:jasmine` you can insert data into the mirrored db before writing your specs (after `describe` and before `it` clauses) and this data would be available for all specs.

Also, you may use `beforeEach()` in order to provide data for each specs, and then you can delete it using `afterEach()`.

[Here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) you can find more info.